# implementing drag and drop swing JList to JTable

Tags: java, swing

I have a jlist of table names from a database and I was wondering if it is possible to drag and drop the table name to another jpanel and for that panel to execute the sql to retrieve store the information of that Table. I am not too savvy with swing. a class or method in which I can get a table to load from a drag and dropped jlist.

Hope this is legible.

Comment: Short answer, yes. You could start by having a look at [Introduction to DnD](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html)

Comment: Long answer -- show us what you've tried, and let's see how we can help you. If you're not sure what to do, check the link provided by @MadProgrammer above, and also search this site for [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+drag+and+drop+jlist).

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855184/drag-and-drop-custom-object-from-jlist-into-jlabel/13856193#13856193), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844574/drag-and-drop-from-jbutton-to-jcomponent-in-java/28844969#28844969), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520610/java-drag-and-drop/15521421#15521421), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381981/how-to-swap-value-of-cell-in-jtable-by-drag-and-drop/24383071#24383071)