# Excel style column-drag in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` with a column of `JButtons` which bring up a window which can have text entered in it when clicked. I'm trying to adapt this without removing the buttons so that clicking and dragging from one button in the column to another copies the associated text of the first button clicked to all buttons dragged over.

Is there a java library method for dragging like this that might be adapted to pull from the inner text, or does someone know of a work around that could accomplish the same thing?

Thanks

Comment: What you're asking is quite a large subject, my first suggestion is to have a look at [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) which will go into detail about the underlying API and functionality and the concepts you will need to grasp

Comment: While strictly not the same thing you're asking for, [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381981/how-to-swap-value-of-cell-in-jtable-by-drag-and-drop/24383071#24383071) demonstrates swapping data from one table/cell with another table/cell using drag'n'drop. It should give you reasonable understanding of what you need to do